# Is it possible to use bootstrap only for forms and nothing else?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a website which was build using custom css. I now want to include a form using the bootstrap 4 styling. When I add bootstrap css (from a cdn), it changes a lot things on the rest of the website (fonts, sizes, padding).

Is there any easy to extract only the form parts of bootstrap css for use?

Comment: I think there is no option like that. But you can put bootstrap css first and the last is your css. So, it could override the bootstrap css.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate a custom version of Bootstrap on the following link.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

You just need to click the checkboxes which you require and the hit the download button to generate your own customized bootstrap.
I won't be available as a CDN you need to download and add the customized scripts and styles.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the info. That link is good, but it still generates styles for base elements, and only works for v3. Might be a good starting point if I can't find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important on the element that you don't want to have bootstrap style

```
element {
    color: blue  !important;
    font-size: 14px !important; 
    ...
}
```